# Pass data from component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm fairly new to Vue and I'm trying to pass data from a component to a view. I'm not sure if I'm using `props` right. I have a dialog and when I save, I want to insert the data to the database. I also want to reuse the `addCustomer()` function that's why I didn't place the function in the component.

**pages/customers.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="items-center justify-between md:flex">
      <Heading
        title="Customers"
        desc="The list of customers or companies you work with."
      />
      <button @click="openModal" class="btn-primary">Add New Customer</button>
    </div>

    <CustomerList class="mt-4" :customers="customers" />
  </div>
  <CustomerDialog
    :is-open="isOpen"
    :close-modal="closeModal"
    :open-modal="openModal"
    :name="name"
    :address="address"
    :email="email"
    :add-customer="addCustomer"
  />
</template>

<script setup>
const client = useSupabaseClient();

const name = ref("");
const address = ref("");
const email = ref("");

const isOpen = ref(false);

function closeModal() {
  isOpen.value = false;
}
function openModal() {
  isOpen.value = true;
}

const { data: customers } = await useAsyncData("customers", async () => {
  const { data } = await client.from("customers").select("*");
  return data;
});

async function addCustomer() {
  if (name.value == "" || address.value == "" || email.value == "") return;

  const { data } = await client.from("customers").upsert({
    name: name.value,
    address: address.value,
    email: email.value,
  });
  customers.value.push(data[0]);
  name.value = "";
  address.value = "";
  email.value = "";
  closeModal();
}
</script>
```

**components/customer/Dialog.vue**

```html
<template>
    <Dialog as="div" @close="closeModal" class="relative z-10">
        <input type="text" id="name" v-model="name" />
        <input type="text" id="address" v-model="address" />
        <input type="email" id="email" v-model="email" />
        <button type="button" @click="addCustomer">Save</button>
        <button type="button" @click="closeModal">Cancel</button>
    </Dialog>
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps([
  "name",
  "address",
  "email",
  "addCustomer",
  "isOpen",
  "closeModal",
  "openModal",
]);
</script>
```

EDIT: The Cancel button in the Dialog works while Save button doesn't.

Comment: If you want to reuse pieces of code, you should look into [composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#composables). I'm not sure to fully understand what you're trying to do here, could you please narrow down your question a bit? What is not working exactly?

Comment: @kissu I'm trying to insert data in the `<CustomerList>`. I want to use the Dialog component as my form so my code won't be as bulky.

Comment: Oh it's probably because you have your state on a given level and the `CustomerDialog` component is on the same level, hence why a listener is not triggered there too. You could probably put a listener on something that wraps both your `button` and your component, then mutate a prop that is passed down to the component. Watching for this prop to be mutated could be a trigger for your action.

Comment: @Larra As `addCustomer` method is available in parent. What you can do is that emit an event on Save button click from the dialog component and then capture the event in parent and invoke `addCustomer` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot bind props directly to the `v-model` directive, in your case you've to use [Multiple v-model bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#multiple-v-model-bindings)

```html
<template>
    <Dialog as="div" @close="closeModal" class="relative z-10">
        <input type="text" id="name" :value="name" @input="$emit('update:name', $event.target.value)"/>
        <input type="text" id="address" :value="adress" @input="$emit('update:address', $event.target.value)" />
        <input type="email" id="email" :value="email" @input="$emit('update:email', $event.target.value)" />
        <button type="button" @click="$emit('add-customer')">Save</button>
        <button type="button" @click="closeModal">Cancel</button>
    </Dialog>
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps([
  "name",
  "address",
  "email",
  "addCustomer",
  "isOpen",
  "closeModal",
  "openModal",
]);

defineEmits(['update:name', 'update:email','update:address','add-customer'])
</script>
```

in parent component :

```html
 <CustomerDialog
    :is-open="isOpen"
    :close-modal="closeModal"
    :open-modal="openModal"
    v-model:name="name"
    v-model:address="address"
    v-model:email="email"
    @add-customer="addCustomer"
  />
```

Comment: It works. After reading the link to the docs, I understand it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can `defineEmits`

```
<script setup>
import {
  TransitionRoot,
  TransitionChild,
  Dialog,
  DialogPanel,
  DialogTitle,
} from "@headlessui/vue";

defineProps([
  "name",
  "address",
  "email",
  "addCustomer",
  "isOpen",
  "closeModal",
  "openModal",
]);

let emit = defineEmits(["add"])
</script>
```

Or better with typescript:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import {
  TransitionRoot,
  TransitionChild,
  Dialog,
  DialogPanel,
  DialogTitle,
} from "@headlessui/vue";

defineProps([
  "name",
  "address",
  "email",
  "addCustomer",
  "isOpen",
  "closeModal",
  "openModal",
]);
let emit = defineEmits<{ (name: "add"): void }>()
</script>
```

Now you can use it in your button:

```
            <button
              type="button"
              class="inline-flex justify-center px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-red-900 bg-red-100 border border-transparent rounded-md hover:bg-red-200 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-red-500 focus-visible:ring-offset-2"
              @click="emit('add')"
            >
              Save
            </button>
```

Now you can listen to this `add` event and trigger your `addCustomer` function

```
  <CustomerDialog
    :is-open="isOpen"
    :close-modal="closeModal"
    :open-modal="openModal"
    :name="name"
    :address="address"
    :email="email"
    @add="addCustomer"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

As `addCustomer` method is available in parent. What you can do is that emit an event on Save button click from the dialog component and then capture the event in parent and invoke addCustomer method.

I just created a below code snippet with Vue 2.* just for your understanding purpose.

```js
Vue.component('customerdialog', {
  data() {
    return {
        customerDetailObj: {}
    } 
  },
  props: ['name', 'address', 'email'],
  mounted() {
    this.customerDetailObj = {
        name: this.name,
      address: this.address,
      email: this.email
    }
  },
  template: `<div><input type="text" id="name" v-model="customerDetailObj.name" />
        <input type="text" id="address" v-model="customerDetailObj.address" />
        <input type="email" id="email" v-model="customerDetailObj.email" />
        <button type="button" @click="$emit('add-customer', customerDetailObj)">Save</button></div>`
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: 'Alpha',
    address: 'Street 1',
    email: 'alpha@testmail.com',
    customerList: []
  },
  methods: {
    addCustomer(customerObj) {
      // Created user details
      this.customerList.push(customerObj);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <CustomerDialog :name="name"
    :address="address"
    :email="email" @add-customer="addCustomer($event)"></CustomerDialog>
  <pre>{{ customerList }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: OP is using Vue3, probably more relevant to use that version.

Comment: @kissu I already mentioned that in my answer. This code snippet is for understanding purpose how to pass the data from a child component to parent. Hope that make sense.

Comment: Doing the same within a Vue3 context can replicate the same behavior tbh.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use [event emitters](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html):

In the dialog:

```html
<button @click="$emit('addCustomer')">save</button>
```

In customers.vue:

```html
<CustomerDialog
    :is-open="isOpen"
    :close-modal="closeModal"
    :open-modal="openModal"
    :name="name"
    :address="address"
    :email="email"
    @add-customer="addCustomer"
  />
```

Comment: I tried this initially while looking at the docs, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Taken from vue 3 docs and still works in vue 3.

Comment: You can totally use Options API with Vue3. You're not obliged to use Composition API. Same goes for Nuxt. @Mises

Comment: Besided @kissu valid point, the code I shared is code that works with the Composition API: "Emitted events can be explicitly declared on the component" but it's not a requirement

Comment: The dialog is a child of the `customers.vue` where the `addCustomer` function is defined that is passed as a prop in the question where emit should be used.

Comment: If it helps, the cancel button in the Dialog works with the `closeModal` function as prop. Only the save button doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Same for close and open modal, those should also be changed to emit's instead op props. But I did not mention that because in my opinion the parent should not manage the is-open prop that is then put back into the dialog. You get a ping pong effect that way

Comment: Usually with Dialogs the dialog handle its own state. If drawn it opens, then it emits on close/cancel/submit and closes itself. That way you can re-use the dialog without all the isOpen logic in every parent